# How to convert Latitude, Longitude to SQL Server geography column in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, geometry

I want to convert latitude and longitude to a geography value, to save the data into a SQL Server table in a `Geography` column.

I tried with

```
GeometryData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.Point(GoogleLatitude, GoogleLongitude, 4326)
```

and with

```
GeometryData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Point(GoogleLatitude, GoogleLongitude, 4326)
```

but with no success.

Comment: "but with no success." what happened?

Comment: Why not just convert in SQL Server.   For example:  Select geoLatLng = geography::Point(42.360081, -71.058884, 4326)

Comment: Note that for geometry longitude comes first in point constructor

Comment: @siggemannen Never understood why in VB they went with Lng/Lat.   In the real world (especially in distress) you always give Lat then Lng.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti That's to do with .NET, not VB. So it will be the same in C#.

Comment: It sounds like you want `SqlGeography` instead of `SqlGeometry` . They are two different types. One works on Euclidean (flat) geometry,  while the other works with the curved topology of a spheroid. Try `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Point(GoogleLongitude, GoogleLatitude, 4326)`.  The 4326 is the SRID (spatial reference identifier) for the WGS84 (World Geodetic System 1984) coordinates. You should check to see if your coordinates use a different system. Note also the swapped coordinate values. If you think of the  coordinates as X/Y, the order makes more sense.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Clearly we're talking about .Net here.  Perhaps I should have been more precise, but then again,  I've never been accused of being pedantic.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti yeah, it's bitten me so many times, especially when one works with WKT strings as well.

Comment: @TN
now i have used your suggestion and i got
Locations.GeographyData ={POINT (nn.nnnnnnn n.nnnnnnn)}
Then i changed the field in the sql table to 
geography

can i now save the above value in the database?

when i saved it to the database i got in the field
<Binärdaten>

when i read it out from the database i got correct values 
SELECT GeographyData.Lat 'Latitude', GeographyData.Long 'Longitude' FROM mylocations

Comment: @user3626339 - I am unsure if you intended the above as a question, but it sounds like you have successfully saved and retrieved your geography points. I suggest that you also test using longitude values > 90 degrees and perhaps calculate some distances using [`.STDistance()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type) to make sure.  You can also `SELECT GeographyData.ToString() which will return a WKT (Well-Known-Text) value like "POINT(<longitude> <latitude>)". (Again, if you think of the coordinates as X/Y, the order makes more sense.)

Comment: @user3626339 - I have a late correction to make to my earlier comments. Although internally, the Geography type stores and manipulates data in X/Y = Longitude/Latitude order, the `SqlGeography.Point()` method takes parameters in Y/X = Latitude/Longitude order. The WKT representation would still be `POINT(X Y)` or `POINT(longitude latitude)`. Thus the second statement in your original post `GeometryData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Point(GoogleLatitude, GoogleLongitude, 4326)` was correct. If you were storing this is a Geography column, I am not sure why this would not have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, assuming this table where we have latitude and longitude values.

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tblLocations | ID | int |
| tblLocations | Location | nvarchar |
| tblLocations | Lat | float |
| tblLocations | Long | float |
| tblLocations | Geo | geography |

So, the first step is to update all rows to having a valid Geography type.

So, then this update on all rows:

```
update tblLocations 
set Geo = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + 
cast([long] as varchar) + ' ' + cast([Lat] as varchar) + ')', 4326)
```

Ok, so now we have a valid Geography column set with the correct values.

Now, say 2 drop downs, we select a row for each, and display this:

[image]

The code behind is VERY convoluted, since we have to convert the Geo column to a SqlChars type (and no easy way to do this). With that, we get the SqlGeograpy type.

So, the code looks like this:

```
    Dim Geo1 As SqlGeography
    Dim Geo2 As SqlGeography


    Dim rst1 As DataRow =
        MyRst($"SELECT Geo.STAsText() FROM tblLocations 
                WHERE ID = {ComboBox1.SelectedValue}", My.Settings.Geo).Rows(0)
    Dim rst2 As DataRow =
        MyRst($"SELECT Geo.STAsText() FROM tblLocations 
        WHERE ID = {ComboBox2.SelectedValue}", My.Settings.Geo).Rows(0)


    Dim s1 As SqlTypes.SqlChars = New SqlTypes.SqlString(rst1(0))
    Dim s2 As SqlTypes.SqlChars = New SqlTypes.SqlString(rst2(0))


    Geo1 = SqlGeography.STPointFromText(s1, 4326)
    Geo2 = SqlGeography.STPointFromText(s2, 4326)

    Dim dMeters As Double = Geo1.STDistance(Geo2)

    If dMeters > 1000 Then
        Label4.Text = "distance in km = " & (dMeters / 1000).ToString("N4") & "Km"
    Else
        Label4.Text = "distance in meters = " & dMeters.ToString("N4")
    End If
```

The routine MyRst simple returns a data table, and I shove that into a data row.

Note VERY close how we cast/convert the SQL Geo type to a text type in the T-SQL query. This returns a SqlChars type, and thus we deal with that, and convert the two results back into a Geography type. (I don't know of a simple/easy way to convert the Geo type directly into a SqlGeography type).

Note that to get/use/enjoy the SQL types, then I suggest adding the NuGet package of

[image]

And thus, you need this:

```
Imports System.Spatial
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

Hence, you need to add a reference to System.Spatial

## Edit: Adding a new row to the database

Of course, the above shows how to query/get the Geo type from the database.

To insert a new row, then this code can be used:

```
    Dim Geo As SqlGeography

    Geo = SqlGeography.Point(txtLat.Text, txtLong.Text, 4326)

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "INSERT INTO tblLocations (Location, Lat, Long, Geo)
         VALUES (@Location, @Lat, @Long, @Geo)"


    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Geo)

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLocation.Text
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Lat", SqlDbType.Float).Value = txtLat.Text
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Long", SqlDbType.Float).Value = txtLong.Text

            Dim sParm As New SqlParameter("@Geo", SqlDbType.Udt)
            sParm.UdtTypeName = "geography"
            sParm.Value = Geo

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(sParm)

            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
    End Using
```

In above, I assume a txtLocation, txtLat, txtLong text boxes on the form.

Eg this:

[image]

As a FYI, in above my table used Float for the Latitude, and Longitude, and in practice those 2 columns should have been of type double, but above does work.

Comment: In your initial `update tblLocations...` statement, you have to be careful when converting floating point values to text to avoid precision loss. The default `cast(... as varchar)` behavior only preserves 6 digits or precision. That might only provide about 1km accuracy at the higher longitudes (Australia, East Asia, Western North America). Better to use a *lossless conversion* option like `convert(varchar, ..., 3)`.  See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ulFmltQF).

Comment: @TN This made me chuckle  https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Point taken.  A `convert(varchar, ..., 1)` (8 digits, ~1m) is probably sufficient for most (not all) purposes. If calculating the area of a small 50 x 150 ft (15 x 45 m) lot, perhaps for tax purposes, even 8 digit accuracy may cause a 5-10% error, For comparison, the Google Maps URL tracks lat/long to 7 fractional digits (9 or 10 digits total.) For an internal data conversion, I'll take the lossless option when available. The extra digits provided in the fiddle were for demo/testing.